# Is calling printf with excess arguments undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, printf, language-lawyer

I wonder if this yields in undefined behaviour:

```
printf("Test %d %s", 123, "abc", "def", "ghi");
```

The first two arguments after the format string match the format string, so these are OK; but the 3rd and 4th arguments are in excess because there are no more corresponding format specifiers.

IMHO `printf()` should simply ignore these excess arguments and there should be no UB. Is this correct?

Comment: I think this question is like asking "Can a function that accepts varargs take any number of arguments?". The mechanism that allows the handling of a variable number of arguments works whatever the particulars of how the function uses those arguments...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, this scenario is explicitly defined by the standard. It is **not** undefined behaviour.

To quote the `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1, *The `fprintf()` function*

> [...] If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, **the excess arguments are evaluated** (as always) **but are otherwise ignored** [...]

Comment: +1, I wasn't aware that it is explicitly defined. BTW "not UB" can be optimized, the "not" and the "un" cancel out, remains "defined behavior".

Comment: As someone who isn't familiar with the implementation of C: why evaluate leftover arguments? Assuming the original format string (first argument) is evaluated before the replacements, this seems like it could be optimized.

Comment: @JulesMazur Not evaluating arguments would mean that `printf("%d", ++i);` would increment `i`, while `printf("foo", ++i);` wouldn't. Which hardly makes any sense and is incredibly obscure. Hence, "as always", the arguments are evaluated before being passed in, then ignored by the function.

Comment: @JulesMazur In addition to Quentin's point, arguments are always evaluated before being passed to functions. Making printf special in that regard would just make all our lives more complicated.

Comment: @JensGustedt - the term "undefined behavior" is defined by the standard; the term "defined behavior" is not. So the correct phrase is, indeed, "not undefined behavior".

Comment: @PeteBecker, how would it define the term "defined"? By saying something like ``the terms "definition" in this International standard is defined to ...'' Have a look a the beginning of Section 3. "Terms, definitions, and symbols" and you see that *defining* things is all what this International Standard is about. And Section 4 says *Undefined behavior is otherwise
indicated in this International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by the
omission of any explicit definition of behavior.*

Comment: @JensGustedt - having spent eight years as project editor for C++ I'm quite familiar with the structure of standards. The term you suggested, "defined behavior," is not a technical term in the standard.

Comment: @PeteBecker, first I am talking of C and not C++, and then what do you think that the partial sentence *explicit definition of behavior* means (that I cited)? Definition of behavior, this is all what the standard is about.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, printf (or any formatting function) will look into only 'n' number of %d, %c, %f..., etc in the format string from the variable list argument. Others are simply ignored.

Comment: How do you know that, and why should we trust your answer?