# printf with multiple pointers as arguments in C

Tags: c, printf, language-lawyer, variadic-functions, format-string

What is the behavior of `printf()` when we supply multiple arguments to it without a format specifier?

Example:

```
int main() 
{
    printf("hello", "hi");
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the compiler produce a warning on compilation of the above program? :

```
warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

If we compile the similar program below:

```
int main() 
{
    char *s1 = "hello";
    char *s2 = "hi";
    printf(s1, s2);
}
```

No warnings are produced. What is the reason for this?

Also, why do both programs output `hello` only, and don't also print `hi`?

Comment: You are using `printf` incorrectly. The first argument should be a format string.  Subsequent arguments should have a format specifier in the format string.  For example: `printf("%s %s", s1, s2);`.  I think `char *s1 "hello %s"; char *s2 = "hi"; printf(s1, s2);` would work, but it's bad practice.

Comment: Your compiler is being helpful (and ignoring the base rule of C) in the first case, it is respecting the base rule *"the programmer knows what she is doing"* in the second case. In these snippets though, the programmer in fact did not know what she was doing (or willingly did something wrong (why???????))

Comment: @atul_pant Please read the description of the function printf. It will be useful for you.

Comment: You may be thinking that `printf` is like print functions in other languages (Python, perl, etc) where you can give it many strings and it will print all of them.  It is not like that.  As Vlad says, you need to read its documentation, or any of the zillions of tutorials on its use that exist online.

Comment: Formally, the first argument is supposed to be a format string, and the subsequent arguments are interpreted based on *format specifiers* embedded in the format string (like `%d`, `%s`, etc).  Since your string `"hello"` doesn't contain any format specifiers, all subsequent arguments are ignored.

Comment: When the first argument to `printf` is a string literal, the compiler will try to check that it makes sense with the rest of the arguments.  But when it's a variable, the compiler doesn't try to do that, because tracing back to find its value can be difficult or impossible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is calling printf with excess arguments undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559109/is-calling-printf-with-excess-arguments-undefined-behaviour)

Answer (score 7):

The C 2018 standard specifies the behavior of `printf` in clause 7.21.6.3, in which paragraph 2 says “The `printf` function is equivalent to `fprintf` with the argument `stdout` interposed before the arguments to `printf`.”

The standard specifies the behavior of `fprintf` in 7.21.6.1, which tells us the second argument (the first argument of `printf`) is a format string and that it may contain various conversion specifications introduced by the character “%”. Thus, in `printf("hello", "hi")`, `"hello"` is a format string with no conversion specifications. In this case, paragraph 2 tells us what happens:

> If the format is exhausted [fully processed] while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.

Thus, in `printf("hello", "hi")`, `"hi"` is ignored, and `"hello"` is a format string that contains only ordinary characters, which are copied to the output stream per paragraph 3.

The compiler warns about `printf("hello", "hi")` because it is able to see that this call contains an excess argument because the format string does not contain a conversion specification for it.

Your compiler does not warn about `printf(s1,s2);` because it does not analyze what `s1` will contain during this call. This sort of analysis is not impossible in this situation, but situations like this are rare: When a programmer uses a pointer to a string as the format string for `printf`, it is usually a string or pointer that is computed, constructed, or selected during program execution, and the manner of this computation is often beyond the ability of a compiler to analyze. Situations where the pointer is clearly a pointer to a fixed string are rare, since they are not frequently useful, so presumably compiler implementors have not found it valuable to implement the code necessary for the compiler to handle these situations.

Answer (score 4):

#### tl;dr: Extra arguments to `printf()` are ignored.

The official [C language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) (the link is to a draft of the C11 version) says the following:

> **§ 7.21.6.1  The `fprintf` function**
>
> 1. ...
> 2. ...  If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated  (as  always)  but  are  otherwise  ignored.  The `fprintf` function  returns  when the end of the format string is encountered.

... and `printf()` is simply `fprintf()` targeted at the standard output file.

About your two code snippets:

- The compiler is giving you a hint, for the first snippet, that the number of arguments doesn't match the number of specifiers in the format string. It's just a courtesy - it's not required to notice this. This also explains why the compiler does *not* notice it for the second snippet. It *could*, but it's too much effort to chase your pointers and check what they point at.
- In both cases, your format string is your first argument to `printf()`, i.e. `"hello"`. That string has no format specifiers, so the `printf()` looks at the `"hello"`, and understands it only needs to print that and doesn't need process any other arguments. That's whi it ignores `"hi"`.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `printf` is the format string, because `printf` is about printing *formatted* data. To specify how to format the data, `printf` uses the first argument. This is different from other languages and libraries where all the parameters (like Python's `print`) are used in the same way and formatting is done through other means.

The first and second examples you provide are both "incorrect" although technically valid because you are passing a format string that does not need any extra argument, so `"hi"` is unused.

What you may want to do instead is:

```
printf("%s %s", "hello", "hi");
```

Answer (score 1):

many compilers know well very well the `printf` function family and read compile time the format string analysing the parameters. `printf("hello",s2);` compiler see that there is no `%...` in the format string and does not expect any other parameters. Warning is issued

if you call `printf(s1,s2);` compiler does not know what is the content of the `s1` and it cannot go through the format string and no warning issued.

Many compilers have special extension to inform them that your function is `printf` like and you want compiler to read the format string - gcc:

```
      extern int
      my_printf (void *my_object, const char *my_format, ...)
            __attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 3)));
```